# Configure and run indicator-sysmonitor on boot at login prompt

Tags: boot, indicator, lightdm

I want to use `indicator-sysmonitor` to display an indicator showing that the network connection is up amongst other things immediately at boot on the lightdm login screen.

I followed these steps to install indicator-sysmonitor,

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

When I try to start it I get a long error message,

```
$ indicator-sysmonitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2135, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/indicator-sysmonitor", line 29, in <module>
    from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 53, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name AppIndicator3, introspection typelib not found
```

What's wrong and how can I configure an indicator for network status via the command line and start it on boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make indicator-sysmonitor as a default indicator on the login screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628720/how-to-make-indicator-sysmonitor-as-a-default-indicator-on-the-login-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1`

Comment: Can you please explain what this command (and what `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1`) does?